# Vuong Test Equivalent for Logistic Regression

Tags: logistic, goodness-of-fit

Is there a test that I can use for a logistic regression that is similar to the Vuong test for OLS?

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. What are the (non-nested) models that you are trying to compare?

Comment: Why don't you just use the Vuong test?  It is not an OLS-specific test.

Answer (score 6):

Indeed, there is a variety of *goodness-of-fit (GoF)* tests that can be applied to *logistic regression* as an alternative to the Vuong test (Vuong, 1989). I think that the following tests can be considered as relative equivalents in the above-mentioned context:

- **Deviance statistics** ($D^2$) test (also referred to simply as *deviance test*);
- **Chi-square test**; for examples, see [this course notes document](http://www.medicine.mcgill.ca/epidemiology/joseph/courses/epib-621/logfit.pdf);
- **Likelihood ratio test (LRT)**; for examples in R and SAS, see [this page](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat504/node/220);
- **GoF tests**, based on so called *pseudo-$R^2$* measures ($R_L^2$ and [some others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression#Evaluating_goodness_of_fit));
- **Akaike's Information Criterion (AIC)**-based tests; also BIC/DIC-based - see [this discussion](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/71667/31372);
- **Hosmer–Lemeshow test** and its **improved versions** (see [this critique](http://www.statisticalhorizons.com/hosmer-lemeshow) and [this answer by Prof. Frank Harrell](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/18772/31372) - the comparison of GoF tests paper he referenced is available online [here](https://stat.duke.edu/~zo2/dropbox/goflogistic.pdf));
- **Stukel's** test - see [this blog post](http://www.statisticalhorizons.com/another-goodness-of-fit-test-for-logistic-regression);
- **Area under the ROC curve (AUC)**-based test: see [this discussion](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/18178/31372) here on *Cross Validated*.

For some *theory* on GoF testing for *categorical models* (in particular, *logistic regression models*), deviance and LRT, as well as *additional examples* in R, Stata and SAS, see [this nice presentation](http://www.stata.com/meeting/italy11/abstracts/italy11_bellocco.pdf).

**Note**

It seems that there are some [issues of significant importance](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat504/node/164), when considering *logistic regression (LR) models*. In particular, it appears to me that *nested vs. saturated* models, *sample size*, *data grouping* in cases with continuous predictors are specifically important in *LR GoF testing* context.

**References**

Hosmer D.W., & Lemeshow S. (1980). A goodness-of-fit test for the multiple logistic regression model, *Communications in Statistics - Theory and Methods, 9*(10), 1043-1069. doi:10.1080/03610928008827941

Vuong, Q. H. (1989). Likelihood ratio tests for model selection and non-nested hypotheses, *Econometrica, 57*(2), 307–333. Retrieved from http://fisher.osu.edu/~schroeder.9/AMIS900/Vuong1989.pdf

Comment: @Billy: My pleasure! Consider upvoting and accepting my answer, if you're satisfied with it.