# Hosmer-Lemeshow test with weighted data

Tags: hypothesis-testing, logistic, statistical-significance, predictive-models, hosmer-lemeshow-test

I am trying to perform Hosmer-Lemeshow test on weighted data (i.e. each observation in a data set has its weight). Unfortunately, I cannot find any literature on how to perform such test. Do you know any method of dealing with this problem?

To give you a background, I try to assess the predictive power of a model on a out-of-sample data. However, these observations have different weight. I tried bootstrapping but I was wondering if there is any purely statistical method for this problem - you know confidence intervals, tests and so on :).

Thanks in advance.
Kuba

Answer (score 4):

For information on *Hosmer-Lemeshow test*, its critique and better **alternatives**, see corresponding links in [my answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/142067/31372). As it has been mentioned in [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/18772/31372) by Prof. Frank Harrell, the alternative methods are implemented in `R` package `rms` (http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/wiki/Main/Rrms). The corresponding paper, describing the above-mentioned methods, can be found [here](https://stat.duke.edu/~zo2/dropbox/goflogistic.pdf).