# Need help for validation models

Tags: goodness-of-fit, calibration

I want to assess and compare the validity of two prediction models in predicting mortality with my patients. According to the other models, I have I have calculated risk of mortality (p) and logit. But I don't know how to assess calibration with a Cox model (using Hosmer-Lemeshow goodness-of-fit test) analysis using a logistic regression model to obtain two derivatives-the slope and the intercept. I asked a lot of my friends for help, but they have no idea.
just like the follow pictures[image]

Comment: Can you say more about your models? Are you comparing a Cox model to a logistic regression model?

Comment: What software are you using?

Comment: thank you for all of you.I just want to validation two logistic regression models.And I learned from other authors that they use a Cox model to assess the calibration.

Comment: Hosmer-Lemeshow is considered obsolete  :  http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/145112/hosmer-lemeshow-test-with-weighted-data/145116#145116