# Poor Discrimination and Good Calibration in Logistic regresion model

Tags: logistic, goodness-of-fit, roc, calibration

I obtained a poor discrimination(AUROC) and a good callibration(according to hosmer lemeshow) in a logistic regression model. How can I address this situation?

Comment: I would not rely on the HL test, in general.

Comment: Hosmer-Lemeshow test is considered obsolete:  http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/145112/hosmer-lemeshow-test-with-weighted-data/145116#145116

Answer (score 1):

Clearly, your explanatory variables doesn't explain the response very well - at least in the model you are using. You could try adding interaction terms, and/or use b-splines of the explanatory variables if they are continuous and their relationship to the response may be nonlinear.

Comment: What is the range of values of the probabilities predicted by your model and how many observations do you have?

Answer (score 0):

HL statistic gives you goodness-of-fit measure of your model, and in your case it's a good model.

When constructing the ROC curve, you plot the points with different probability thresholds. While you may have a well-fitted model, that doesn't necessary mean you have good classification performance over some of the thresholds. A possibility is the skewness of your data.